# How to change the 'object sender'?

Tags: c#

I create DataGridView in makeDataGridView function, and maybe datagridview rightclick -> appear context menu

This is sample code

```
public void click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        if(e.button == MouseButtons.Right) {
               ContextMenuStrip menu = new ContextMenuStrip();
               ToolStripItem insert = menu.Items.Add("insert");
               insert.Click += new EventHandler(context_menu_click);
        }
}

public void context_menu_click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        / *
           Other event and
           printing .txt file from DataGridView
        */
}
```

I want to print a .txt file from datagridview in 'context_menu_click' function.
The sender of `click` function is DataGridView, but `context_menu_click` sender is ToolStripMenu.

So, How can I print a .txt file from DataGridView in `context_menu_click` function?

Comment: Have you tried passing in the `sender` and `e` parameters from the `click` method? I.e. `insert.Click += new EventHandler(context_menu_click(sender, e));`

Comment: Why don't you use `DataGridView` directly in `context_menu_click` event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void context_menu_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    /*
        Other event and
        printing .txt file from DataGridView
    */
    var item = sender as ToolStripItem  ;
    if (item != null)
    {
        DataGridView gv = item.Tag as DataGridView;
        Console.WriteLine(gv.Name);
    }
}
private void dataGridView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        ContextMenuStrip menu = new ContextMenuStrip();
        ToolStripItem insert = menu.Items.Add("insert");
        insert.Tag = sender;
        insert.Click += new EventHandler(context_menu_click);
        menu.Show(this.dataGridView1.PointToScreen(new Point(e.X, e.Y)));
    }
}
```

You can add current `DataGridView` as `Tag` to the `ToolStripItem` you just create

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get the DataGridView in your click event

```
((ContextMenuStrip)((ToolStripMenuItem)sender).GetCurrentParent()).SourceControl
```